# Limit of a sum of roots proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

Given the sequence:
$$a_n=\alpha\sqrt{n+a}+\beta\sqrt{n+b}\ with\ \  \alpha,\beta,a,b\in\mathbb{R}\ and\ \alpha,\beta\neq0$$
Prove that $$\lim_{  n\to \infty} a_n = 0\ iff\ \alpha=-\beta$$

I start the proof by supposing that $\alpha\neq\beta\ and\ \alpha\neq-\beta$.Then I have:
$$a_n=\alpha\sqrt{n+a}+\beta\sqrt{n+b}$$
$$a_n=\frac{\alpha\sqrt{n+a}+\beta\sqrt{n+b}}1\cdot\frac{\alpha\sqrt{n+a}-\beta\sqrt{n+b}}{\alpha\sqrt{n+a}-\beta\sqrt{n+b}}$$
$$a_n=\frac{\alpha^2(n+a)-\beta^2(n+b)}{\alpha\sqrt{n+a}-\beta\sqrt{n+b}}$$
$$a_n=\frac{n(\alpha^2-\beta^2)+\alpha^2a-\beta^2b}{\alpha\sqrt{n+a}-\beta\sqrt{n+b}}$$
$$a_n=\frac{n(\alpha^2-\beta^2)}{\sqrt n(\alpha-\beta)}\cdot\frac{\frac{n(\alpha^2-\beta^2)}{n(\alpha^2-\beta^2)}+\frac{\alpha^2a-\beta^2b}{n(\alpha^2-\beta^2)}}{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-\beta}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{n+a}{n}}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha-\beta}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{n+b}{n}}}$$

$$a_n=\frac{\sqrt n(\alpha-\beta)(\alpha+\beta)}{(\alpha-\beta)}\cdot\frac{1+\frac{\alpha^2a-\beta^2b}{n(\alpha^2-\beta^2)}}{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-\beta}\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha-\beta}\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}}}$$

$$a_n=\sqrt n(\alpha+\beta)\cdot\frac{1+\frac{\alpha^2a-\beta^2b}{n(\alpha^2-\beta^2)}}{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-\beta}\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha-\beta}\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}}}$$

Now for the limit of $a_n$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \infty(\alpha+\beta)\cdot\frac{1+\frac{\alpha^2a-\beta^2b}{\infty(\alpha^2-\beta^2)}}{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-\beta}\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{\infty}}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha-\beta}\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{\infty}}}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \pm\infty\cdot1=\pm\infty$$
Note:Because at the beginning of the proof I supposed that $\alpha\neq\beta\ and\ \alpha\neq-\beta$ I don't have any indeterminate cases or divisions by 0.

With this I have shown that if $\alpha\neq\beta\ and\ \alpha\neq-\beta$ then the limit of $a_n$ is plus or minus infinity.

The only cases left to be checked are:
1.$\alpha=\beta$
$$a_n=\alpha\sqrt{n+a}+\alpha\sqrt{n+b}$$
$$a_n=\alpha(\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt{n+b})$$
And the limit of $a_n$ is clearly plus or minus infinity(depending on $\alpha$).
2.$\alpha=-\beta$
$$a_n=\alpha\sqrt{n+a}-\alpha\sqrt{n+b}$$
$$a_n=\alpha(\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt{n+b})$$
$$a_n=\alpha(\frac{n+a-n-b}{\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt{n+b}})$$
$$a_n=\alpha(\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt{n+b}})$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\alpha\cdot\frac{a-b}{\infty}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\alpha\cdot0$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$$

And so I have proven what was required.

My questions are:
1.Is this a complete and good proof? If not what is missing or what is wrong?
2.The need to prove this arose when I was given the equation:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}[a\sqrt{n+2}+(a^2+a-3)\sqrt{n}]=0\ solve\ for\ a\in\mathbb{R} $$
are there any other ways of solving this?

PS:I have not learned yet about limits of functions, asymptotics, derivatives and integrals.

Comment: Its correct and very detailed. But answer from Simeon is a much simpler way to reach the same conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that, as $n$ tends to $+\infty$,
$$
\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}} = \alpha\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}} + \beta\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\alpha + \beta
$$
so we can see that $\lim a_n = 0 \implies \alpha+\beta = 0$.

For the second implication $\alpha+\beta = 0 \implies \lim a_n = 0$, your proof (case 2, $\alpha=-\beta$) works perfectly well.

---

*Given the postscript in the OP, I know that the following will not satisfy @classius, but this is the best (and shortest) proof I can think of.*

**Alternative shorter proof**

Using $\sqrt{1+u} = 1 + O(u)$ as $u \to 0$, we can write
$$
a_n = \sqrt{n}\left(\alpha\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}} + \beta\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}}\right)= (\alpha + \beta)\sqrt{n} + O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
$$
So, the equivalence $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0 \iff \alpha+\beta = 0$ is now obvious.

Comment: as n tends to 0?

Comment: @classius: What? no, $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: that's what it says on the in the first line

Comment: @classius. Oh it was a typo, thanks!

Comment: That done, now I can't understand how $\lim a_n = 0 \implies \alpha+\beta = 0$ resulted from $\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}} = \alpha\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}} + \beta\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\alpha + \beta
$

Comment: @classius: If $\lim a_n = 0$, what is $\lim \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ ?

Comment: It would be 0... That's it I totally forgot about that, it is given that lim $a_n$=0. Thanks!!!